# Slim framework for API and consuming with Retrofit

Tags: rest, retrofit, slim, retrofit2

I try to return list of "question" with slim framework and consuming them in my android application with retrofit.

```
$app->get('/questions', function() use ($app, $bdd, $logger) {

    $stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM questions');
    $stmt->execute();
    $questions = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $app->render(200, $questions);

});
```

give

```
{
  "0":{
      "id":"1",
      "userID":"1",
      "choice_1":"choice 1",
      "choice_2":"choice 2",
      "count_1":"213",
      "count_2":"165",
      "dateAdd":"2016-03-06"
   },
   "1":{
      "id":"2",
      "userID":"1",
      "choice_1":"choice 1",
      "choice_2":"choice 2",
      "count_1":"0",
      "count_2":"0",
      "dateAdd":"2016-03-04"
   },
   "error":false,
   "status":200
}
```

and in my retrofit api service :

```
@GET("questions")
Call<ArrayList<Question>> getQuestions();
```

and call with :

```
APIService api = getRetrofit().create(APIService.class);
Call<ArrayList<Question>> call = api.getQuestions();

call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Question>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ArrayList<Question>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        questions.addAll(response.body());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Log.d("QFragment", "loadData error" + t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

But isn't correct because api give me object list and in my app i need an array:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

Some help ?

---

**RESULT**

Ok so with Jackub answer i resolve my problem, just add registerTypeAdapterFactory to my GsonBuilder() to get only payload like :

```
public class ItemTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

    final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
    final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

        public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
            delegate.write(out, value);
        }

        public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
            if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                if (jsonObject.has("payload")) {
                    jsonElement = jsonObject.get("payload");
                }
            }

            return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
        }
    }.nullSafe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there are keys `error` and `status` so the array indexes are transformed into keys.

You can do something like

```
$payload = ['payload' => $questuons];

$app->render(200, $payload);
```

and adapt your consuming of the response in android app.